# Does anyone have a working example of AspNetCore .Net 6 + Swashbuckle + OData Web API

Tags: odata, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle, .net-6.0, aspnet-api-versioning

Does anyone have a working example of AspNetCore Web API with:

- .Net 6
- OData (including $batch)
- Swashbuckle
- versioning (api/v1,api/v2,etc)

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured it out. Working example is [here at github](https://github.com/rgudkov-uss/aspnetcore-net6-odata-swagger-versioned)

Comment: Taking a look at your repo, good job!

Answer (score 1):

At long last, ASP.NET API Versioning has official support for OData 8.0 on .NET 6.0, including the API Explorer extensions.

Examples:

- [Basic](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/93bd8dc7582ec14c8ec97997c01cfe297b085e17/examples/AspNetCore/OData/ODataBasicExample)
- [Using Conventions](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/93bd8dc7582ec14c8ec97997c01cfe297b085e17/examples/AspNetCore/OData/ODataConventionsExample)
- [Advanced](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/93bd8dc7582ec14c8ec97997c01cfe297b085e17/examples/AspNetCore/OData/ODataAdvancedExample) (mixing OData and non-OData endpoints)
- [OpenAPI](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/93bd8dc7582ec14c8ec97997c01cfe297b085e17/examples/AspNetCore/OData/ODataOpenApiExample) (formerly known as "Swagger")

New Packages:

- [Asp.Versioning.OData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Asp.Versioning.OData)
- [Asp.Versioning.OData.ApiExplorer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Asp.Versioning.OData.ApiExplorer)